# Steiner’s Pedal Polygon Theorem

Tags: calculus, geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

Does anyone know of books or papers containing a proof of Jakob Steiner’s   Theorem that the area of a pedal polygon with vertices $P_i$ where i= 1…..n with respect to M is invariant for M on a circle centred on Steiner’s Curvature Centroid K,given by:
$$K=\frac{\sum_i\sin(2\theta_i)P_i}{\sum_i \sin(2\theta_i)}$$
where $ \theta_i$ are the internal angles 1….n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paris Pamfilos' website has a page on [pedal polygons](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/PedalPolygons.html) that I think answers your question. The web also has references to Steiner's 1838 paper  *Über den Krümmungs-Schwerpunkt ebener Curven* , but that would be in German.

Comment: Thank you for this